# Error pip installing wheel file from github repository (to download pycocotools)

Tags: tensorflow, github, pip, pycocotools

I am installing Tensorflow (1.15.0) in order to perform some deep learning object detection, but am having trouble pip installing pycocotools. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usR2LQuxhL4&t=134s) tutorial, which is an updated tutorial originally from YouTube channel Sentdex. I am also using the Anaconda Prompt for this purpose.

After creating and activating a conda environment and installing all the needed packages (TensorFlow, lxml, etc.), I am trying to run the command `pip install pycocotools` package, but get the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-au01c73g'
       cwd: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f_16w712\pycocotools\
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
  running build_ext
  cythoning pycocotools/_mask.pyx to pycocotools\_mask.c
  C:\anaconda3\envs\object\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f_16w712\pycocotools\pycocotools\_mask.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
  Running setup.py clean for pycocotools
Failed to build pycocotools
Installing collected packages: pycocotools
    Running setup.py install for pycocotools ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bjfh6urg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\Include\pycocotools'
         cwd: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f_16w712\pycocotools\
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
    copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
    copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
    copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
    copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\pycocotools
    running build_ext
    skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f_16w712\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bjfh6urg\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\Include\pycocotools' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Apparently, there is a wheel file that needs to be downloaded from [this](https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi#egg=pycocotools) github repository, under the subdirectory PythonAPI. I ran this code to do so:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi#egg=pycocotools^subdirectory==PythonAPI
```

The following error is produced:

```
Collecting pycocotoolssubdirectory==PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi to c:\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-c_lq0qhi\pycocotoolssubdirectory
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\anaconda3\envs\object\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_lq0qhi\\pycocotoolssubdirectory\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_lq0qhi\\pycocotoolssubdirectory\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-0mcbi3nr'
         cwd: C:\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c_lq0qhi\pycocotoolssubdirectory\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\anaconda3\envs\object\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c_lq0qhi\\pycocotoolssubdirectory\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I successfully install this repository? I need the wheel file so that I can proceed with the pycocotools installation. Note: I have installed the latest version of `pip`, so that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it as follows:

```
pip install pycocotools-windows
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/169).